# Telegram show old name of Channel on Private link join

Tags: telegram

i have Telegram  channel and make it private now , the weird things is when i click on Private Link the message box that Opened and question about,do you want to join channel ""

show my very old and first name of channel that i use only 1 day in my first day , how can i rename that ?!

I search for any option to do that but no success at all

i know there must be the way , cause i see some channels rename and change it a lot , how can i change this ?

thanks

Comment: I think you may find this question a better fit for Super User instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks for replay , whats super User ?

Comment: It's another site on the Stack Exchange network. Stack Overflow is just one part of the network and intended for programming questions. If you click the symbol at the top right of the bar above (the one with links to questions, jobs, documentation... and your info like reputation and badges) you can get a full list of Stack Exchange sites. Super User is more intended for questions such as how to use specific software, networks and hardware.

Comment: thank u , i didn't know about this , sorry if i post wrong place

Comment: It can sometimes be hard to find out which question is best put where. Originally there was only Stack Overflow but the place has steadily expanded. When unsure, you can click that icon, then the link "help" after the current community and find out there which questions are intended for the site.